# Converting decimal number to currency in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal

I'm trying to figure out how to get my results to just show two decimal places and currency if I can.
Right now I'm getting this:

```
PARTID       PARTIDCOUNT    AVGPLANAMT
1001            27          17.02148148148148148148148148
1002            13          54.18615384615384615384615384 
1003             3          467.4166666666666666666666666
1009             5          862.27  

SELECT DISTINCT
D.PARTID,
COUNT(D.PARTID) AS PARTIDCOUNT,
AVG(D.PLANAMOUNT) AS AVGPLANAMT
FROM PARTS....
```

Comment: Do you have a requirement to round or truncate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbeb82/3/0)):

```
SELECT PARTID, COUNT(*) AS PARTIDCOUNT, 
       TO_CHAR(AVG(PLANAMOUNT), 'L999,999,999.00') AS AVGPLANAMT
FROM PARTS
GROUP BY PARTID
```

For the second parameter I am using `'L999,999,999.00'` which will account for any number up to 1 billion.  If you need to accommodate a larger number then do something like: `'L999,999,999,999,999.00'`.

Comment: For the localized currency symbol, you might want to use `L` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1):

To show only two decimal places you can use the ROUND feature

```
ROUND(AVG(D.PLANAMOUNT), 2) AS AVGPLANAMT
```

More info on `ROUND()` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm).

What do you mean by `and currency`? Do you just want a currency symbol in front $?

If so, try this.

```
COLUMN AVGPLANAMT FORMAT $990.99
```

For more info, you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm).